# Why arguments passed from one function to another with $@ are "lost" in this shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write some shell scripts (to use with Docker and VSCode Dev Containers) but I'm totally new to this.  I'm trying to replicate the [utility script found here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devcontainers/features/main/src/nix/utils.sh) which is, indeed, quite simple:

```
# Checks if command exists, installs it if not
# check_command <command> "<apt packages to install>" "<apk packages to install>" "<dnf/yum packages to install>"
check_command() {
    command_to_check=$1
    shift
    if type "${command_to_check}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        return 0
    fi
    install_packages "$@"
    return $?
}

# Installs packages using the appropriate package manager (apt, apk, dnf, or yum)
# install_packages "<apt packages to install>" "<apk packages to install>" "<dnf/yum packages to install>"
install_packages() {
    if type apt-get > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        apt_get_update_if_needed
        apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends $1
    elif type apk > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        apk add $2
    elif type dnf > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        dnf install -y $3
    elif type yum > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        yum install -y $3
    else
        echo "Unable to find package manager to install ${command_to_check}"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

One is supposed to include `utils.sh` and run `check_command curl` to get `curl` installed if needed. In `my install.s`h it's what I'm doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Import common utils
. ./utils.sh

 # Verify dependencies
apt_get_update_if_exists
check_command curl
curl -o /usr/local/foo https://foo.example
```

This script fails:

> ./install.sh: line 10: curl: command not found

Adding debug lines inside `check_command` show that `install_packages "$@"` is empty, that is argument "curl" isn't passed correctly to `install_packages`.

Any help understanding why this is happening is much appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing `type ...` with `command -v ...`. Example: `type apk > /dev/null 2>&1` with `command -v apk /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `check_command` function which calls `install_packages` with all its arguments is only called with a single argument. Naturally `install_packages` will also only receive one but you're making it reference `$2` and `$3`. Also you might want to place them inside double quotes.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was pretty sure was my fault, as that library is an official microsoft repository. I'll try to understand $2 and $3 (why they defined install_packages that way).